# Customization of the InputField on the FormPage

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I want to understand how to set up input fields on the pages so that you can insert large texts. How can I make Input Field the higher? For example for this code:

```
CloudDeploy[
    FormPage[{"text"->"String"}, 
    Column[StringSplit[#text]]&]
]
```

I can use the custom controls:

```
FormPage[
    {"text100x100" -> 
    <|
        "Interpreter"->"String", 
        "Control"->InputField[#, FieldSize-> {100,100}]&
    |>}, 
    Column[StringSplit[#text100x100]]&
]
```

But it does not work:

[image: text100x100]

Comment: It works, you just missed `(..)` that is: `"Control" -> (InputField[#, FieldSize -> {100, 100}] &)`

Comment: @Kuba, yes, in the notebook it works, but after performing `CloudDeploy` in the FormPage showed InputFiled with one-line height

Comment: This `FormPage[{"text100x100" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "String", 
     "Control" -> (InputField[#, FieldSize -> {100, 100}] &)|>}, 
  Column[StringSplit[#text100x100]] &] // 
 CloudDeploy[#, Permissions -> "Public"] &` gives me a screen size input field.

Comment: @Kuba, Thanks! I had a mistake after adding brackets to the expression `(..)`